# Programmatically installing printer drivers from Windows Update

Tags: c++, windows, drivers, printers, windows-update

I'd like to be able to programmatically install a selected printer driver from Windows Update.  I've tried doing so with something like the following code, but the only search results returned were the collection of Windows Language Packs that I haven't installed.

```
IUpdateSearcher *pUpdateSearcher = NULL;

// Snip instantiation code

pUpdateSearcher->put_ServerSelection(ssWindowsUpdate);
pUpdateSearcher->put_CanAutomaticallyUpgradeService(VARIANT_TRUE);
pUpdateSearcher->put_IncludePotentiallySupersededUpdates(VARIANT_TRUE);
pUpdateSearcher->put_Online(VARIANT_TRUE);

hr = pUpdateSearcher->Search(
        BSTR(TEXT("Type='Driver' AND IsInstalled=0 AND IsHidden=0")),
        &pSearchResult
    );
```

Is there a way I could programmatically search Windows Update for printer drivers in a way similar to how you can search Windows Update when manually installing a printer?